# Как сделать параметры для командной строки своего приложения? c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Такая вот задача. Мне нужно сделать для своего приложения возможность, чтобы можно было через командную строку (cmd) передать какие то значения или параметры при запуске. Например browser.exe --new window "https://ya.ru". Он откроет в браузере окно с данным url. Есть ли возможность как то сделать подобные параметры (--new window) для программы в c#? Может есть какой-то способ кодом это написать или как?

Comment: `args` видели? Вот это ваши аргументы, которые так передаете. Обрабатывайте их, делая на их основе все нужное. Ну а если нужно чет готовое, то ищите в NuGet нужный пакет, их много, даже вон Microsoft [свой](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/commandline/) пилят.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ честно ток сейчас узнал про args. Хорошо , а вы не знаете они подойдут для wpf?

Comment: Любое приложение - это по сути консоль (условно) ) Везде есть стартовая точка, где есть все теж `args`, которые вы можете как угодно парсить, и что угодно с ними делать.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ просто в wpf нету метода  main(string[] args), по сравнению с консольным приложением. То есть можно просто взять их и объявить или как?

Comment: В WPF они немного скрыты. Вы можете либо в `App.xaml.cs` написать `override`, затем нажать пробел и студия должна вам выдать варианты, там выбираете `OnStartup`, создаст нечто такое: `protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) {...}`, вот у `e` будут аргументы (`e.Args`). Либо вы можете написать в любом месте приложения такое: `string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();`, и вот опять ваши аргументы запуска.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ благодарю.